# Hide console using structlog

Tags: python, structlog

Can structlog be used with **pythonw** to only log in file ?

Importing structlog fails when pythonw is used to run the python code because `sys.stdout` is `None`.
The error is raised  in file `structlog/_config.py` when `sys.stdout.isatty()` is called.

Here is a simple test that reveals the issue.

```py
# python try_import_structlog.pyw --> success
# pythonw try_import_structlog.pyw --> fail

with open("result.txt", "a") as file:
    try:
        import structlog
    except Exception as error:
        file.write(f"import failed: {error}")
    else:
        file.write("import succeeded")
```

https://github.com/hynek/structlog/issues/313

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in structlog that will be fixed with next release! I think it might be out as soon as this weekend.